# QTP close Firefox when I stop a test and open another one

Tags: qtp

I'm new at QTP, I've tried to learn it with some tutorial and documentation. I need to update a lot of existing test for a Java application (a big one) that run in Firefox.

And I have a problem with a lot of them. They used internal action, but also existing action that are in a test named : 'tools'. Those existing action are used by the other test.

One action in 'tools' is to click on a link, but it's id and text have change and QTP don't recognize it.

I have done the following to update the link in the object repository:

I launch my test, it's run the application in Firefox. I stop the test on the web page where the link is. Then, I try to update the link in the object repository. But it's read only. So, I open the test name 'tools' where is the action.

I open the object repository, the object for the link is here, and I can update it. But when I open a another test, QTP automatically close Firefox!

I've tried to run my test in maintenance mode and update mode, but it do not update the link. The only solution I have found is to manually open the application, go to the web page, and then open the test 'tools' and update the link. The application is really big and i have a lot of test with a lot of link and datagrid that are not recognize.

Is there a way to force QTP to not close Firefox?  It will be much faster.
(Browser cleanup is not check).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be a Patch issue. As QTP 10 supports Firefox 3.0.x version only you might face many issue with later version of Firefox. Which QTP version do you use 10 or 11?

It will be good if you find the relevant patch for Firefox and install. Might be it can fix your issue.

Comment: This answer offered a link, which is now 404 - the whole site has been deleted.